# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getNetwork')" with gnosis-safe-sdk+hardhat

Tags: hardhat, gnosis-safe, hardhat-deploy, gnosis

Snap of code:

````
            const { Contract, Signer, providers } = require('ethers')
            const Safe = require('@safe-global/safe-core-sdk')
            const EthersAdapter = require('@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib')
            // const { ethers } = require('ethers')
            const SafeService = require('../gnosis/service')
            const SafeEthersSigner = require('../gnosis/signer')

            console.log("Setup provider")
            console.log("Setup SafeService")
            const service = new SafeService(process.env.SERVICE_URL)
            console.log("Setup Signer")
            const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
            
            console.log("Setup SafeEthersSigner", process.env.DEPLOYER_SAFE)
            const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter.default({ ethers: hre.ethers, owner })

            const safe = await Safe.default.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress: process.env.DEPLOYER_SAFE })
            const safeSigner = new SafeEthersSigner(safe, service, owner.provider)
            const contract = new Contract("0xe50c6391a6cb10f9B9Ef599aa1C68C82dD88Bd91", ["function pin(string newMessage)"], safeSigner)
            const proposedTx = await contract.functions.pin(`Local time: ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`)
            console.log("USER ACTION REQUIRED")
            console.log("Go to the Safe Web App to confirm the transaction")
            console.log(await proposedTx.wait())
            console.log("Transaction has been executed")
    ```
    ENV:

DEPLOYER_SAFE=0xD934fbEd3CB5dAa5A82C14089cAcaD6035718163
SERVICE_URL=https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global
````